# Can´t add item to ListBox in different form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I´m trying to build an application that can store different persons in a ListBox-control.

My ListBox-control is located in **Form1** and so is this method that´s giving me some problem:

```
  public void addPersonToList(Person person) {
            string newPerson = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " " + person.age;

            personList.Items.Add(newPerson);

 }
```

In another Form, I call the addPersonsToList-method like this:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
  form1.addPersonToList(person);
```

Now, I´ve checked (while debugging) that the string **newPerson** in addPersonToList actually stores the correct string. **The problem is that the string won´t show up in my ListBox**(named personList).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Using `new`, you are creating a brand new instance of an item.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.addPersonToList(person);
```

So this code creates a new instance of Form1 and adds an item to that instance, which is probably not the one you are viewing. You somehow need a reference to the instance being displayed so you can reference that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. You have any example on how to reference the original Form?

Comment: As I indicated, you'd need a reference to it somehow. Possibly as a parameter or property of the form, but it really depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

To reference an existing open form, do this:

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
{
     if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Form1))
     {
          Form1 frmTemp = (Form1)frm;
          frmTemp.addPersonToList(person);
          fromTemp.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Similarly for MDI forms :

```
foreach (Form frm in MdiParent.MdiChildren)
{
}
```